# Elasticsearch query_string exact match

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index containing `field` video with value `1.flv`. If I do the following query:

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "query": "2.flv"
    }
}
```

query still returns all records with 1.flv.

Can anyone point me to right solution?

Here is sample data returned for 1.flv (as you can see, nothing contains 2.flv!)

```
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 8,
    "max_score" : 0.625,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "videos",
      "_type" : "comment",
      "_id" : "_meta",
      "_score" : 0.625,
      "fields" : {
        "video" : "1.flv",
        "body" : "Really?"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "videos",
      "_type" : "comment",
      "_id" : "0fYsYOTHT7O-7P6CVi7l3w",
      "_score" : 0.625,
      "fields" : {
        "video" : "1.flv",
        "body" : "fadsfasfas"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "videos",
      "_type" : "comment",
      "_id" : "O9VjgFdmQra6hYxwMdGuTg",
      "_score" : 0.48553526,
      "fields" : {
        "video" : "1.flv",
        "body" : "Search is hard. Search should be easy."
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "videos",
      "_type" : "comment",
      "_id" : "A6k3FEKKSzKTSAVIT-4EbA",
      "_score" : 0.48553526,
      "fields" : {
        "video" : "1.flv",
        "body" : "Really?"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "videos",
      "_type" : "comment",
      "_id" : "eFnnM4PrTSyW6wfxHWdE8A",
      "_score" : 0.48553526,
      "fields" : {
        "video" : "1.flv",
        "body" : "Hello!"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "videos",
      "_type" : "comment",
      "_id" : "ZogAiyanQy6ddXA3o7tivg",
      "_score" : 0.48553526,
      "fields" : {
        "video" : "1.flv",
        "body" : "dcxvxc"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "videos",
      "_type" : "comment",
      "_id" : "O0HcT7aGTrqKQxF25KsOwQ",
      "_score" : 0.37158427,
      "fields" : {
        "video" : "1.flv",
        "body" : "Hello!"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "videos",
      "_type" : "comment",
      "_id" : "l2d53OFITb-etooWEAI0_w",
      "_score" : 0.37158427,
      "fields" : {
        "video" : "1.flv",
        "body" : "dasdas"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your mapping and the expected result?

Comment: And also analyzer settings?

Comment: @shyos I'm not sure how can I get it. I need 1.flv exact match 1.flv and 2.flv exact match ONLY 2.flv (not 1.flv)

Answer (score 6):

What you're seeing is the result of the standard tokenizer (part of the default/standard analyzer), which tokenizes on among other things, the period character (`.`). See [this play](https://www.found.no/play/gist/7890922#analysis) for a quick example of how it's analyzed.

There's many ways to accomplish what you want with Elasticsearch, such as updating the mapping and changing the analyzer for the `video` field to for example the `keyword` analyzer as mentioned above, possibly using a multi field type, configuring the field mapping as `index: not_analyzed`, etc, but a simple solution that might work well enough for you is to make sure the `AND` operator is being used.

By default, the [query string query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) uses the `OR` operator:

> `default_operator`: The default operator used if no explicit operator is specified. For example, with a default operator of OR, the query capital of Hungary is translated to capital OR of OR Hungary, and with default operator of AND, the same query is translated to capital AND of AND Hungary. The default value is OR.

So, either be explicit with the operator or set it as the default. [This play](https://www.found.no/play/gist/7890922) also shows both these techniques in action (Search #1 and Search #2-tabs in the bottom right pane).